# how to run jenkins-agent.jnlp at startup as admin

Tags: jenkins, windows-10

I have downloaded the jenkins-agent.jnlp to windows and created shortcut to windows startup folder.
the agent connected successfully. however when Jenkins trigger cmd, access denied error is occured.

I tried to terminated Jenkins agent and open cmd as admin, run the jenkins-agent.jnlp from cmd then the error is not happend.

How do I execute above automatically instead of manual run cmd as admin then execute the jenkins-agent.jnlp?

Comment: You can simply setup a task scheduler job or change the status of service to automatic and restart os. It will work.

Comment: how to run it as admin from task scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Create a task on task scheduler and select user like this.
write administrator name and check the name and create the task as admin.

[image]